# binarize dataframe column and split other column values accordingly

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2],
    'y':[1.2,3.4,5.2,4.8,5.4,5.9,4.3,2.1,1.2,6.7,2.9,7.3]
})
```

I'm looking for a way to binarize `x` and split `y` according to groups in `x`
This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
1  1.2  0  0    0  0
1  3.4  0  0    0  0 
1  5.2  0  0    0  0
1  4.8  0  0    0  0
0  0    1  5.4  0  0
0  0    1  5.9  0  0
0  0    1  4.3  0  0
0  0    1  2.1  0  0
0  0    0  0    1  1.2
0  0    0  0    1  6.7
0  0    0  0    1  2.9
0  0    0  0    1  7.3
```

To achieve the above result I essentially created new columns
`df2['x1'] = (df.x==1).astype(int), df2['y1']=df2.x1*df.y` and so on but I'm hoping there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `get_dummies`

```
d = pd.get_dummies(df.x)
pd.concat(
    {'x': d, 'y': d.mul(df.y, axis=0)},
    axis=1
).swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

    0       1       2     
    x    y  x    y  x    y
0   0  0.0  1  1.2  0  0.0
1   0  0.0  1  3.4  0  0.0
2   0  0.0  1  5.2  0  0.0
3   0  0.0  1  4.8  0  0.0
4   1  5.4  0  0.0  0  0.0
5   1  5.9  0  0.0  0  0.0
6   1  4.3  0  0.0  0  0.0
7   1  2.1  0  0.0  0  0.0
8   0  0.0  0  0.0  1  1.2
9   0  0.0  0  0.0  1  6.7
10  0  0.0  0  0.0  1  2.9
11  0  0.0  0  0.0  1  7.3
```

---

#### `interleave`

Different combining concept

```
from more_itertools import interleave

x = pd.get_dummies(df.x)
y = x.mul(df.y, 0)
x = x.add_prefix('x_')
y = y.add_prefix('y_')
x.join(y)[[*interleave(x, y)]]

    x_0  y_0  x_1  y_1  x_2  y_2
0     0  0.0    1  1.2    0  0.0
1     0  0.0    1  3.4    0  0.0
2     0  0.0    1  5.2    0  0.0
3     0  0.0    1  4.8    0  0.0
4     1  5.4    0  0.0    0  0.0
5     1  5.9    0  0.0    0  0.0
6     1  4.3    0  0.0    0  0.0
7     1  2.1    0  0.0    0  0.0
8     0  0.0    0  0.0    1  1.2
9     0  0.0    0  0.0    1  6.7
10    0  0.0    0  0.0    1  2.9
11    0  0.0    0  0.0    1  7.3
```

---

#### Creative

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.x)
r = np.arange(len(df))
out = np.zeros((len(df), len(u) * 2))
out[r, i * 2] = 1
out[r, i * 2 + 1] = df.y

pd.DataFrame(out, df.index)

      0    1    2    3    4    5
0   1.0  1.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   1.0  3.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2   1.0  5.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3   1.0  4.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   0.0  0.0  1.0  5.4  0.0  0.0
5   0.0  0.0  1.0  5.9  0.0  0.0
6   0.0  0.0  1.0  4.3  0.0  0.0
7   0.0  0.0  1.0  2.1  0.0  0.0
8   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.2
9   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  6.7
10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.9
11  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  7.3
```

Or

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.x)
r = np.arange(len(df))
out = np.zeros((len(df), len(u), 2))
out[r, i, 0] = 1
out[r, i, 1] = df.y

pd.DataFrame(out.reshape(len(df), -1), df.index)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative

```
pd.concat({x:y.assign(x=1) for x , y in df.groupby('x')},1)
Out[431]: 
      0         1         2     
      x    y    x    y    x    y
0   NaN  NaN  1.0  1.2  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  1.0  3.4  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  1.0  5.2  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  1.0  4.8  NaN  NaN
4   1.0  5.4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   1.0  5.9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   1.0  4.3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   1.0  2.1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.2
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  6.7
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.9
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  7.3
```

---

`crosstab`

```
s=pd.crosstab([df.x,df.y],df.x)
s1=s.copy()
s1[:]=s1.values*(s1.index.get_level_values(1).values[:,None])
pd.concat([s,s1],axis=1,keys=['x','y'])
Out[479]: 
       x          y          
x      0  1  2    0    1    2
x y                          
0 2.1  1  0  0  2.1  0.0  0.0
  4.3  1  0  0  4.3  0.0  0.0
  5.4  1  0  0  5.4  0.0  0.0
  5.9  1  0  0  5.9  0.0  0.0
1 1.2  0  1  0  0.0  1.2  0.0
  3.4  0  1  0  0.0  3.4  0.0
  4.8  0  1  0  0.0  4.8  0.0
  5.2  0  1  0  0.0  5.2  0.0
2 1.2  0  0  1  0.0  0.0  1.2
  2.9  0  0  1  0.0  0.0  2.9
  6.7  0  0  1  0.0  0.0  6.7
  7.3  0  0  1  0.0  0.0  7.3
```

Comment: @Yuca aha, make it happen . :-)

Comment: man, I genuinely find it remarkable how you come up with that, great stuff